# AWS lambda connecting to multiple database instances

Tags: aws-lambda, micronaut-aws

I have a java/micronaut aws lambda that connects to one database, and its all working okay.

I need to now connect to multiple databases for some specific business reasons. I looked into using the following method
[micronaut-data : multiple data sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797107/micronaut-data-multiple-data-sources)

I just wanted to know whether aws lambdas could support handling multiple connections.. i presume this would be the case as when it starts up it would create a connection.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation in AWS lambda for such use cases. You can create more connections if you want.

Initialise all connections before the invocation starts and reuse them for subsequent calls.

Furthermore you have the option to create a database proxy like described here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-database.html